# Call LocationListener Service from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-location, locationlistener

I want to call LocationListener Service from BroadcastReceiver, So I can get current location of device and call my API on server after every 5 minutes in backend, even if application is not running.

So, I have created class with BroadcastReceiver, Which will call my LocationListener Service. In this service, I want to get location and save it in db.

The problem is, I am not able to call LocationListener Service from BroadcastReceiver. BroadcastReceiver running well.

Code,

Run BroadcastReceiver in AlarmManager.

```
public void LocationClicked(View view){
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 10000;

        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

BroadcastReceiver class file,

```
public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static int count = 0;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        count++;
        Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running " + count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, LocationUpdateService.class);
        context.startService(myIntent);
    }
}
```

"I'm running " is coming.
LocationListerner Service file,

```
public class LocationUpdateService extends Service implements LocationListener {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double ss = location.getLatitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

Here what do I need to change to make it work ?
And tell me If I am doing it in wrong way.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not able to call LocationListener Service", exactly? Are you getting an Exception? Is it crashing?

Comment: No, nothing is happening. no crashing. I have defined everything in manifiest file too.

Comment: I want to call myLocationListerner service, from BroadcastReceiver class after every 5 minutes.

Comment: "...nothing is happening." - Well, yeah, your Service isn't doing anything. You need to register it as a listener with a location service/client.

Comment: From service/client means, I need to implement service from GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener ?

Comment: Merely implementing more interfaces isn't going to do anything. You need to setup a `GoogleApiClient`, and request location updates be sent to your Service. There's an [example here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java) using an Activity, but the setup would be similar for your Service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97739/discussion-between-keval-patel-and-mike-m).

Comment: protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
Here what should I pass instead of this parameter (3rd parameter). how to create LocationListener object here. ?

Comment: `this` is what you want. If your IDE is complaining, then your Service isn't implementing the correct `LocationListener` interface. If you are actually using the Fused Location API, then the interface is `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener`.

Comment: Thank you so much, finally it's working. :)
Last que. : is is good idea to make web api call in current service with location in background ?

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily be a bad idea. Depends on your situation.